# How to convert XML output from php file to JSON format

Tags: php, json, xml, amazon-web-services

Hi I am a beginner programmer who wants to convert my XML output to JSON format and eventually make an Ajax call to html. The XML output is generated by Example.php with reference to amazon_api_class.php and [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W00vM.jpg). The answers I have found on the site seems to work for input AND output xml files, while in my scenario I have only the output xml file.

[Here is my XML output](http://www.codesend.com/view/e193cc5736708c44c451a547c8fd5c19/) ( the output is too long to fit in this body)

Here are my php files:
*Example.php*

```
<?php
require_once('amazon_api_class.php');

    $obj = new AmazonProductAPI();

    // original 
    try
    {
        $result = $obj->getItemByKeyword("X-Men Origins",
                                       AmazonProductAPI::DVD
                                       );
    }

    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

  //print_r returns $result in XML format 
    print_r($result);

    //$json = json_encode($result);
    //$array = json_decode($json, true);

    //echo $array['Items']['Item']['ASIN'];

    echo "Sales Rank : {$result->Items->Item->SalesRank}<br>";
    echo "ASIN : {$result->Items->Item->ASIN}<br>";
    echo "<br><img src=\"" . $result->Items->Item->MediumImage->URL . "\" /><br>";
?>
```

*amazon_api_class.php* (which is referenced to Example.php)

```
<?php

    require_once 'aws_signed_request.php';

    class AmazonProductAPI
    {
        /**
         * Your Amazon Access Key Id
         * @access private
         * @var string
         */
        private $public_key     = "AKIAJETPMOLIUXXXXXXX";

        /**
         * Your Amazon Secret Access Key
         * @access private
         * @var string
         */
        private $private_key    = "eHpNEaUwsf+HXXXXXXXXXXQGg7Ic2w+K5Gb6rYa";

        /**
         * Your Amazon Associate Tag
         * Now required, effective from 25th Oct. 2011
         * @access private
         * @var string
         */
        private $associate_tag  = "mpXXXX-20";

        /**
         * Constants for product types
         * @access public
         * @var string
         */

        /*
            Only three categories are listed here. 
            More categories can be found here:
            http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/APPNDX_SearchIndexValues.html
        */
        const MUSIC = "Music";
        const DVD   = "DVD";
        const GAMES = "VideoGames";


        /**
         * Check if the xml received from Amazon is valid
         * 
         * @param mixed $response xml response to check
         * @return bool false if the xml is invalid
         * @return mixed the xml response if it is valid
         * @return exception if we could not connect to Amazon
         */
        private function verifyXmlResponse($response)
        {
            if ($response === False)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not connect to Amazon");
            }
            else
            {
                if (isset($response->Items->Item->ItemAttributes->Title))
                {
                    return ($response);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Invalid xml response.");
                }
            }
        }


        /**
         * Query Amazon with the issued parameters
         * 
         * @param array $parameters parameters to query around
         * @return simpleXmlObject xml query response
         */
        private function queryAmazon($parameters)
        {
            return aws_signed_request("com", $parameters, $this->public_key, $this->private_key, $this->associate_tag);
        }


        /**
         * Return details of products searched by various types
         * 
         * @param string $search search term
         * @param string $category search category         
         * @param string $searchType type of search
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function searchProducts($search, $category, $searchType = "UPC")
        {
            $allowedTypes = array("UPC", "TITLE", "ARTIST", "KEYWORD");
            $allowedCategories = array("Music", "DVD", "VideoGames");

            switch($searchType) 
            {
                case "UPC" :    $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemLookup",
                                                    "ItemId"        => $search,
                                                    "SearchIndex"   => $category,
                                                    "IdType"        => "UPC",
                                                    "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");
                                break;

                case "TITLE" :  $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemSearch",
                                                    "Title"         => $search,
                                                    "SearchIndex"   => $category,
                                                    "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");
                                break;

            }

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);

        }


        /**
         * Return details of a product searched by UPC
         * 
         * @param int $upc_code UPC code of the product to search
         * @param string $product_type type of the product
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function getItemByUpc($upc_code, $product_type)
        {
            $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemLookup",
                                "ItemId"        => $upc_code,
                                "SearchIndex"   => $product_type,
                                "IdType"        => "UPC",
                                "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);

        }


        /**
         * Return details of a product searched by ASIN
         * 
         * @param int $asin_code ASIN code of the product to search
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function getItemByAsin($asin_code)
        {
            $parameters = array("Operation"     => "ItemLookup",
                                "ItemId"        => $asin_code,
                                "ResponseGroup" => "Medium");

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);
        }


        /**
         * Return details of a product searched by keyword
         * 
         * @param string $keyword keyword to search
         * @param string $product_type type of the product
         * @return mixed simpleXML object
         */
        public function getItemByKeyword($keyword, $product_type)
        {
            $parameters = array("Operation"   => "ItemSearch",
                                "Keywords"    => $keyword,
                                "SearchIndex" => $product_type);

            $xml_response = $this->queryAmazon($parameters);

            return $this->verifyXmlResponse($xml_response);
        }

    }

?>
```